# A list whose "Nil" carries a value?

Tags: list, haskell, algebraic-data-types, pattern-synonyms

Does some standard Haskell library define a data type like this

```
data ListWithEnd e a = Cons a (ListWithEnd e a)
                     | End e
```

That is a list whose terminating element carries a value of a designated type?

So `ListWithEnd ()` is isomorphic to `[]` and `ListWithEnd Void` is isomorphic to infinite streams. Or, viewed differently, `ListWithEnd e a` is very close to [`ConduitM () a Identity e`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.4/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ConduitM)..

Comment: I've not seen it. Perhaps it would be easier (wrt working with predefined functions) to define `newtype ListWithEnd e a = LWE ([a], e)`?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I need `e` to be really in the constructor at the end, as I'm experimenting with functions that compute `e` while constructing the list.

Comment: Trying to express it in terms of standard stuff, `type LWE e a = Free ((,) a) e` comes  to mind.

Comment: Can't you just use `([a],e)`?

Comment: Very similar to a `Producer a Identity e` from `pipes` as well. Following the analogy, a function that decoded bytes into chars and returned any undecoded leftovers would have type `forall e . ListWithEnd e Word8 -> ListWithEnd (ListWithEnd e Word8) Char`.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: That wouldn't quite be the same because a list does *not* have to have an end. Particularly, `([a], Void)` would be isomorphic to `Void` and not to infinite streams.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Could you convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can define `ListWithEnd` as follows:

```
import Control.Monad.Free

type LWE a e = Free ((,) a) e
```

We generally have an expectation that abstract or generic representations should reward us with an overall reduction of boilerplate. Let's see what this representation provides us.

In any case, we shall define a pattern synonym for the cons case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern x :> xs = Free (x, xs)
infixr 5 :>
```

We can map, fold and traverse over the end element:

```
fmap (+1) (0 :> Pure 0) == (0 :> Pure 1)
traverse print (0 :> Pure 1) -- prints 1
```

The `Applicative` instance gives us very neat concatenation:

```
xs = 1 :> 2 :> Pure 10
ys = 3 :> 4 :> Pure 20

xs *> ys          == 1 :> 2 :> 3 :> 4 :> Pure 20 -- use right end
xs <* ys          == 1 :> 2 :> 3 :> 4 :> Pure 10 -- use left end
(+) <$> xs <*> ys == 1 :> 2 :> 3 :> 4 :> Pure 30 -- combine ends
```

We can map over the list elements, if a bit tortuously:

```
import Data.Bifunctor -- included in base-4.8!

hoistFree (first (+10)) xs == 11 :> 12 :> Pure 10
```

And we can make use of `iter`, of course.

```
iter (uncurry (+)) (0 <$ xs) == 3 -- sum list elements
```

It would be nice if `LWE` could be a `Bitraversable` (and `Bifunctor` and `Bifoldable`), because then we could access the list elements in a more generic and principled way. For this we definitely need a newtype:

```
newtype LWE a e = LWE (Free ((,) a) e) deriving (lots of things)

instance Bifunctor LWE where bimap = bimapDefault
instance Bifoldable LWE where bifoldMap = bifoldMapDefault
instance Bitraversable LWE where bitraverse = ...
```

But at this point we might think about just writing the plain ADT out and writing the `Applicative`, `Monad` and `Bitraversable` instances in a couple of lines of code. Alternatively, we could use `lens` and  write a `Traversal` for the list elements:

```
import Control.Lens

elems :: Traversal (LWE a e) (LWE b e) a b
elems f (Pure e)  = pure (Pure e)
elems f (x :> xs) = (:>) <$> f x <*> elems f xs
```

Thinking further along this line, we should make a `Lens` for the end element. This is a bit of a bonus over the generic `Free` interface, since we know that every finite `LWE` must contain exactly one end element, and we can make this explicit by having a `Lens` for it (rather than a `Traversal` or `Prism`).

```
end :: Lens (LWE a e) (LWE a e') e e'
end f (Pure e)  = Pure <$> f e
end f (x :> xs) = (x :>) <$> end f xs
```